# awk replace string with newline

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have never used awk or sed. I am trying to replace

```
aaa
{
```

with

```
aaa
{
    bbb
```

I tried different solutions using sed/awk, but couldn't figure it out.

```
awk '{gsub("aaa\n{", "aaa\n{\tbbb")}1' file.txt
```

Could you please help me on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print} /^aaa$/{i=NR} /^{$/ && NR==i+1 {print "\tbbb"}' File
```

Output:

```
aaa
{
        bbb
sdjdhsjdhdsd
ds
ddsdsdsd
aaa
{
        bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^aaa$/!b;n;/^{$/a\\tbbb' file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk with getline

```
awk '/aaa/ {print;getline} /{/ { print ;print "\tbbb";next}1 ' file
```